# How do I clear the selection of a selected node in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to deselect selected node (in after select event)?

Comment: Try myTree.SelectedNode = null

Comment: I was tring IsSelected, but has only get... anyway thx.

Comment: Try this treeview.SelectedNode.Selected = false;

Comment: The WinForms TreeView will not change the highlighted Node when the TreeView.SelectedNode property is set to 'null as long as the TreeView retains focus. And, the WinForm TreeView 'IsSelected Property is read-only: there is no 'Selected Property.

Comment: _The WinForms TreeView will not change the highlighted Node when the TreeView.SelectedNode property is set to 'null as long as the TreeView retains focus_ Wrong.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you are faced with issues like this (dealing with *what api you need to use*) You should consult MSDN and then figure it out.

Now, see the [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc9ba94b) page on msdn. It has a [Selectednode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode) property which says :

> If no TreeNode is currently selected, the SelectedNode property is null.

Also, it has a *getter* and *setter*. So my best bet is:

```
myTreeView.SelectedNode = null;//will deselect it
```

Comment: lol :) It is isn't it?! Issue is that I've seen quite a few people faced with the challenge of understanding that API has to be learned over time and with documentation. That how everyone else did it!

Comment: Granted, asking questions is part of the learning process - it shouldn't be scoffed at - but I usually wait until I've exhausted other avenues - like documentation.

Comment: I have tried adobe example and i face a error: 'SelectedNode cannot be assign to--- it is read only prperty'.
 i achieve it by seting propertly it like 
 MyTreeView.SelectedNode.Selected = false;

Comment: @JatinderSharma The documentation says clearly : `public TreeNode SelectedNode { get; set; }` . So you should perhaps double check the framework, version etc. Possibly you're talking about WPF and this question is about windows forms.

Comment: i have tried this in web forms not in wpf or not window forms

Comment: @JatinderSharma Precisely. That's a **different** class altogether with the same name. The class in my answer is `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` -> **Windows.Forms** cannot be used in the web. You could post a separate question specially asking for a web solution.

Comment: fyi: in the WinForms TreeView SelectedNode = null; will not change the appearance of the highlighted Node as long as the TreeView retains focus; and, the 'IsSelectred Property is read-only: there is no 'Selected Property.